# How do I process an image to produce formatted images subject to some rules?

Tags: image, image-processing

Imagine a digital picture of a flower. I am looking for an algorithm and a platform to use it, in which it will generate a series of "derivative images", in which each image shows the moulding of the flower in a time series. The rules for choosing areas and the colours in the derivative images will be instructed by the artist, and the final output must look as if one has actually filmed a similar flower becoming mouldy (like green), where the contours of objects remain fixed. It should also be based on a randomised algorithm where each generated sequence of images will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the description of the task, the program will have to perform complex image processing, involving estimation of an object's three-dimensional position and orientation from a 2d image, generation of a filter based on that data and its application on the image. This can be accomplished with the [OpenCV library](http://opencv.org/).

Comment: Thank you. If the image is only a drawing of a flower but not an actual photo of it, do I still need to take into account the 3D aspect of the object?

Comment: Depends on how the image was drawn. If it's a very simple(think kid's drawing), just determining the rose's borders and applying the mould effect on it uniformly would do. If drawn in a realistic enough style(light and shadows, etc.) disregarding that aspect could result in unrealistic and and "fake" effect.

Comment: How important is the size of the image for such processing? what would be the maximum image size to handle in that case?

Comment: Usually it's more convenient for the image to be small enough to be contained in the computer's RAM, but specifics of a task's implementation are again, specific to the task, and your question doesn't provide enough details to cover them all(which it probably shouldn't either way). I suggest that you research the OpenCV documentation and play around with it to better understand whether that's what works for you .